# GWT DataGrid wrap height

Tags: css, gwt, layout, datagrid

I have a GWT DataGrid, which i put into a TabLayoutPanel. The TabLayoutPanel is wrapped by a ResizePanel with a given width/height. If i do not specify the width/height, my TabLayoutPanel does not appear at all.

So my ui.xml looks like this

```
<g:ResizeLayoutPanel width="100EM" height="100EM">

    <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabMonitoringPanel" barHeight="3" barUnit="EM" animationDuration="1000">

<g:header size="7">DataGrid</g:header>

            <c:DataGrid ui:field="m_jmxDataGrid" autoFooterRefreshDisabled="false" visible="true"></c:DataGrid>
        </g:tab>
    </g:TabLayoutPanel>

</g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
```

My problem here is that the DataGrid even it has a few rows (1 or 2) it takes the full height of the viewport. I would like it to be wrapped to the last row that is visible. Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of the `ResizeLayoutPanel` to auto and setting the row height of the table to something specific.